# KeyboardEvent.code

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, onkeypress

I like use the keyboard layout independent codes. I thought the way to apply the [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.code) specification, but the  script:

> 1. window.onkeypress=press
> 2. ...
> 3. press=function(event){ echo(event.code, typeof event.code) }

results 'undefined,undefined'.

What is wrong in above script?

The `event.key` work well, but the `event.keyCode` not exact with all keyboard layout, ie. HU, DE etc. results '0' on some national keys.

Comment: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.code#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Jahh, many thanks, nightly.mozilla.org, fine works **THE** event.keyCode, BUT the AltLeft not released by release, but must press again. Is it a bug, or system setup problem?... This button the prefix for menu hotkeys, sorry... We had better use window.addEventListener(), because it supplies control button events, too.

Answer (score 1):

[`KeyboardEvent.code` is not yet implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-code) in most current browsers.

It should be in [Firefox starting version 38](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) and there are [tickets for Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263724). I was not able to find any information for IE, which only supports a previous draft of DOM3 events.